# Multiplication in R of specific portion of a dataframe

Tags: r, multiplication

I have a dataset from 1966 to 2002, I want change the units(multiply values by 0.305) of some of the values in the dataframe from 1967 to 1973and want the rest of the values to remain as they are.

Sample Data

```
    Date         A01        
1   1966/05/07  4.870000    
2   1966/05/08  4.918333    
3   1966/05/09  4.892000    
4   1966/05/10  4.858917    
5   1966/05/11  4.842000    
6   1967/03/18  4.89517         
7   1966/05/07  4.870000    
8   1966/05/08  4.918333    
9   1966/05/09  4.892000    
10  2000/05/10  2.858917    
11  2001/05/11  1.842000    
12  2002/03/18  0.89517
```

Desired Outcome

```
    Date         A01        
1   1966/05/07  1.4843  
2   1966/05/08  1.4990  
3   1966/05/09  1.49108 
4   1966/05/10  1.480992    
5   1966/05/11  1.48565 
6   1967/03/18  1.4920          
7   1966/05/07  1.4843  
8   1966/05/08  1.4991  
9   1966/05/09  1.4910  
10  2000/05/10  2.858917    
11  2001/05/11  1.842000    
12  2002/03/18  0.89517
```

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `df %>% mutate(A01 = ifelse(year(Date) >= 1967 & year(Date) <= 1973, A01 * 0.305, A01))`

Comment: `df %>% mutate(A01 = ifelse(Date>= as.Date("1966/05/07", format="%Y/%m/%d") & Date <= as.Date("1973/01/27", format="%Y/%m/%d"), A01 * 0.305, A01))` - should actually even work without the parsing, but better to be clear. If your "Date"-column isn't yet a Date type and you run into any issues because of that, you can parse it the same way using `as.Date` or functions from the great `lubridate` package

Comment: Based on the data that you have shared only row 6 should be changed since it is in the year 1967. Why others row change?

Comment: The units of the values to change are in Feet and I want it in Metres. The rest of the data is already in metres

Comment: @alex_jwb90, why does this code stop multiplying @ 1970/10/17

Comment: No way to tell. It shouldn't. Is your column "Date" a Date type vector for sure? Can you `dput` your dataframe to let us reproduce this behavior?

Comment: needed to read the date column before using the df. I used: df <- read.csv("A01.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE), to fix to issue

Answer (score 2):

Convert `Date` to date class, extract the `year` from it and multiply `A01` with 0.305 if it is between 1967 and 1974 or with 1 otherwise.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date), 
         A01 = A01 * c(1, 0.305)[(between(year(Date), 1967, 1974)) + 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

An option in `base R` would be get the 'year' part from the Date column to create a logical index ('i1'), subset the 'A01' column, multiply by 0.305 and assign it back to the original column

```
i1 <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(df1$Date, '%Y/%m/%d'), "%Y")) %in% 1966:1973
df1$A01[i1] <- df1$A01[i1] * 0.305
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("1966/05/07", "1966/05/08", "1966/05/09", 
"1966/05/10", "1966/05/11", "1967/03/18", "1966/05/07", "1966/05/08", 
"1966/05/09", "2000/05/10", "2001/05/11", "2002/03/18"), A01 = c(4.87, 
4.918333, 4.892, 4.858917, 4.842, 4.89517, 4.87, 4.918333, 4.892, 
2.858917, 1.842, 0.89517)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `ifelse`

```
transform(
  df,
  A01 = A01 * ifelse(as.numeric(format(as.Date(Date), "%Y")) %in% 1967:1973, 0.305, 1)
)
```